Need Help Setting Up two Isolated Networks with ZTE F6600 Router
I'm seeking assistance with a networking setup using my ZTE F6600 router. Here's the scenario:
Setup:

Main Router: ZTE F6600 (provided by ISP)
Devices: Linux server connected to the main router
Requirement: I want to share internet access with a family in the same building. To achieve this, I plan to use an access point router and an Ethernet cable connected to one of the LAN ports of my main router.

Objective:

Create two isolated networks:

One network for me (existing setup with the Linux server).
Another network for the family sharing the internet.



Challenges:

I couldn't find a solution specific to my ZTE F6600 router.
While exploring, I came across VLANs as a potential solution, but I'm unsure if my router supports this feature. I only see it when creating a new WAN connection. Additionally, I noticed a SSID isolation checkbox, but it seems to apply only to wireless WiFi connections.

Request for Assistance:

Can anyone provide guidance on how to achieve this setup with my ZTE F6600 router?
the two networks?
If VLANs are not an option, are there any alternative methods I could explore?

Any help or pointers would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Start by researching to see if your router supports VLANs. That is step #1 and you can do that yourself.

@music2myear I am sorry if I didn't make it clear but my router doesn't support VLANs.

@John does a switch with VLANs support work for this case?
